# Как сохранить состояние textView?

Tags: android

```
package com.example.a1.onsaveinstancestate;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    String data = "+2point";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.point);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { // Здесь из одного Activity инициирую изменения в другом
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Result.class);
                intent.putExtra("result", data.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> Ниже Activity2, который получает значение String, но почему-то не сохраняет при перезапуске приложения(основная проблема)

```
package com.example.a1.onsaveinstancestate;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Result extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView getString;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        getString = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        getString.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("result"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема в передаче данных между Activity или в сохранении данных при перезапуске приложения?

Comment: для начала, почему вы записываете в TextView переменную объект типа Button?

Comment: Проблема в том, что изменяет textView, но потом когда перезапускаю приложение не сохраняется значение textView

Comment: исправил, но все-равно не работате

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воскользуйтесь `PreferenceManager`, каждый раз обновляйте значение при его изменении. Сохранить значение можно так:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Main2Activity.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("data", data);
editor.apply();
```

Получить так:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Result.this);
String newData = prefs.getString("data", "");
TextView getString = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
getString.setText(newData);
```

Comment: Как это получит TextView?

Comment: В вашем случае так: `getString.setText(newData);`, вместо `getString.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("result"));`

Comment: извините,еще вопрос. Что за lastData

Comment: Я поправил свой ответ, так должно быть понятнее.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!!!Все работает

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад помочь

Comment: А можно ли сделать два PreferenceManager на один TextView

Comment: @DeveloperChingis `PreferenceManager` можно использовать для хранения любого количества параметров. В данном случае он хранит значение с ключом "data", Вы можете записать второе значение с ключом "data2".

Comment: textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Result.this);
        String newData = prefs.getString("data", "");
        textView.setText(newData);
        SharedPreferences newone = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Result.this);
        String two = newone.getString("data2", "");
        textView.setText(two); когда так пишу, выполняет только data2

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47750/discussion-between-developer-chingis-and--).

Answer (score 3):

> В Android есть несколько способов хранения данных:
>
> Preferences - в качестве аналогии можно привести виндовые INI-файлы
>
> SQLite - база данных, таблицы
>
> обычные файлы - внутренние и внешние (на SD карте)

Если вам нужно сохранить только одну строку между запусками приложения, вполне подойдёт `SharedPreferences` (пример использования смотрите [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html)).